# Returning last row of each group meeting logical index condition in pandas multindexed dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, multi-index

Looking to return a dataframe which contains the last row *(the row with most recent date index)* of each group, where the second level of the multi-index is filtered by a logical indexing condition.

Here is a toy example included to explain better:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dates  = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/4/2018').to_pydatetime().tolist() * 2
ids    = ['z7321', 'z7321', 'z7321', 'z7321', 'b2134', 'b2134', 'b2134', 'b2134']

arrays = [ids, dates]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['key', 'date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index, columns=['change'])

print(df)

                   change
key   date
z7321 2018-01-01 -0.701605
      2018-01-02 -0.934580
      2018-01-03  0.186554
      2018-01-04  0.417024
b2134 2018-01-01  0.682699
      2018-01-02 -0.913633
      2018-01-03  0.330347
      2018-01-04 -0.706429
```

The condition would be to return the last row where `df[df.index.get_level_values(1) <= datetime(2018, 1, 2)]`

The desired output looks like this:

```
                   change
key   date
z7321 2018-01-02 -0.934580
b2134 2018-01-02 -0.913633
```

Additional Considerations:

1. Directly selecting the rows using `df[df.index.get_level_values(1) == datetime(2018, 1, 2)]` isn't an option since the second index level (date level) may not contain an exact date match for the specified value of `datetime(2018, 1, 2)`
2. The date index may not contain the same values across the key groups/index. i.e. 'z7321' could have different dates in the second level index than 'b2134'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only the first and last rows of each group with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927414/get-only-the-first-and-last-rows-of-each-group-with-pandas)

Comment: See also: [`.tail()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.tail.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-tail).

Comment: Yes it does help answer the question, I didn't come across it in my searching. Applying .tail(1) also works.

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote my toy example, I ended up finding a way to get the desired output. Hopefully this solution is helpful to someone else or perhaps can be improved upon.

The following provides the desired output:

```
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(1) <= datetime(2018, 1, 2)].groupby(level='key', as_index=False).nth(-1)
print(df1)

                   change
key   date
z7321 2018-01-02 -0.934580
b2134 2018-01-02 -0.913633
```

Which also works for cases where the second index level is inconsistent across the first level groups:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

dates = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/4/2018').to_pydatetime().tolist()
dates += pd.date_range(start='12/29/2017', end='1/1/2018').to_pydatetime().tolist()

ids   = ['z7321', 'z7321', 'z7321', 'z7321', 'b2134', 'b2134', 'b2134', 'b2134']

arrays = [ids, dates]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['key', 'date'])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randn(len(index)), index=index, columns=['change'])
print(df)

                    change
key   date
z7321 2018-01-01 -1.420757
      2018-01-02 -0.297835
      2018-01-03  0.693520
      2018-01-04  0.909420
b2134 2017-12-29 -1.577685
      2017-12-30  0.632395
      2017-12-31  1.158273
      2018-01-01 -0.242314


df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values(1) <= datetime(2018, 1, 2)].groupby(level='key', as_index=False).nth(-1)
print(df1)

                    change
key   date
z7321 2018-01-02 -0.297835
b2134 2018-01-01 -0.242314
```