# How to filter pandas dataframe so that the first and last rows within a group are retained?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a `dataframe` like below:

```
data = [
    [123456, "2017", 150.235],
    [123456, "2017", 160],
    [123456, "2017", 135],
    [123456, "2017", 135],
    [123456, "2017", 135],
    [123456, "2018", 202.5],
    [123456, "2019", 168.526],
    [123456, "2020", 175.559],
    [123456, "2020", 176],
    [123456, "2021", 206.667],
    [789101, "2017", 228.9],
    [789101, "2018", 208],
    [789101, "2018", 208],
    [789101, "2018", 208],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        "ID",
        "year",
        "value",
    ],
)
df
```

In this `dataframe` I have an `ID` column and 2+ `years`. The `year` columns can contain 1 or more `value` columns.

I would like to filter this `dataframe` so that all of the **earliest** `year` rows (even if there are duplicate `values`) and all of the **latest** `year` rows (again, even if there are duplicate `values` I want them).

My desired output is:

[image]

I found another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927414/get-only-the-first-and-last-rows-of-each-group-with-pandas) question that was similar:

```
g = df.groupby("ID")

(pd.concat([g.head(1), g.tail(1)])
   .drop_duplicates()
   .sort_values('ID')
   .reset_index(drop=True))
```

but it only first to the first `value` within the first `year` and I want all of the `values`.

Can anyone please advise?!

Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
out = df.groupby("ID", group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda x: x[(x.year == x.year.min()) | (x.year == x.year.max())]
)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
        ID  year    value
0   123456  2017  150.235
1   123456  2017  160.000
2   123456  2017  135.000
3   123456  2017  135.000
4   123456  2017  135.000
9   123456  2021  206.667
10  789101  2017  228.900
11  789101  2018  208.000
12  789101  2018  208.000
13  789101  2018  208.000
```

Answer (score 2):

You can figure out the "first" and "last" years per group, i.e., per ID. Then broadcast those with `transform`, and compare with the entire year column to filter out:

```py
# Variabilize because we transform twice
>>> g = df.groupby("ID")["year"]

# These are first & last years per group;
# with `transform` they are "broadcasted" (repeated) to match column length
>>> firsts = g.transform("first")
>>> lasts  = g.transform("last")

# if a year equals to groups' firsts OR lasts, keep them
>>> df.loc[df["year"].eq(firsts) | df["year"].eq(lasts)]
```

to get

```py
        ID  year    value
0   123456  2017  150.235
1   123456  2017  160.000
2   123456  2017  135.000
3   123456  2017  135.000
4   123456  2017  135.000
9   123456  2021  206.667
10  789101  2017  228.900
11  789101  2018  208.000
12  789101  2018  208.000
13  789101  2018  208.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:

```
import pandas as pd

# Your data
data = [
    [123456, "2017", 150.235],
    [123456, "2017", 160],
    [123456, "2017", 135],
    [123456, "2017", 135],
    [123456, "2017", 135],
    [123456, "2018", 202.5],
    [123456, "2019", 168.526],
    [123456, "2020", 175.559],
    [123456, "2020", 176],
    [123456, "2021", 206.667],
    [789101, "2017", 228.9],
    [789101, "2018", 208],
    [789101, "2018", 208],
    [789101, "2018", 208],
]

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        "ID",
        "year",
        "value",
    ],
)
# Find the earliest and latest years for each "ID"
earliest_years = df.groupby("ID")["year"].min()
latest_years = df.groupby("ID")["year"].max()

# Filter the DataFrame to include earliest and latest year rows
filtered_df = df[df.apply(lambda row: row["year"] in [earliest_years[row["ID"]], latest_years[row["ID"]]], axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)

print(filtered_df)
```

Output:

```
       ID  year    value
0  123456  2017  150.235
1  123456  2017  160.000
2  123456  2017  135.000
3  123456  2017  135.000
4  123456  2017  135.000
5  123456  2021  206.667
6  789101  2017  228.900
7  789101  2018  208.000
8  789101  2018  208.000
9  789101  2018  208.000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
[123456, "2017", 150.235],
[123456, "2017", 160],
[123456, "2017", 135],
[123456, "2017", 135],
[123456, "2017", 135],
[123456, "2018", 202.5],
[123456, "2019", 168.526],
[123456, "2020", 175.559],
[123456, "2020", 176],
[123456, "2021", 206.667],
[789101, "2017", 228.9],
[789101, "2018", 208],
[789101, "2018", 208],
[789101, "2018", 208],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
data,
columns=[
    "ID",
    "year",
    "value",
],
)

 # Convert 'year' column to datetime type for sorting
 df['year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['year'])

 # Sort the DataFrame by 'ID' and 'year'
 df_sorted = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'year', 'value'])

 # Get the first and last rows within each group
 first_rows = df_sorted.groupby('ID').head(1) 
 last_rows = df_sorted.groupby('ID').tail(1)

  # Concatenate the first and last rows
  result = pd.concat([first_rows, last_rows])

  print(result)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to include an arbitrary number of [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) conditions:

```
out = df.merge(
    df.groupby('ID')['year'].agg(['min', 'max'])
      .stack().droplevel(1)
      .reset_index(name='year')
      .drop_duplicates() # optional
 )
```

Output:

```
       ID  year    value
0  123456  2017  150.235
1  123456  2017  160.000
2  123456  2017  135.000
3  123456  2017  135.000
4  123456  2017  135.000
5  123456  2021  206.667
6  789101  2017  228.900
7  789101  2018  208.000
8  789101  2018  208.000
9  789101  2018  208.000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `nsmallest()` and `nlargest()`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['year']

df.loc[g.nsmallest(1,keep='all').droplevel(0).index.union(g.nlargest(1,keep='all').droplevel(0).index)]
```

or using `rank()`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['year']

df.loc[g.rank(method = 'dense').eq(1) | g.rank(method = 'dense',ascending=False).eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
        ID  year    value
0   123456  2017  150.235
1   123456  2017  160.000
2   123456  2017  135.000
3   123456  2017  135.000
4   123456  2017  135.000
9   123456  2021  206.667
10  789101  2017  228.900
11  789101  2018  208.000
12  789101  2018  208.000
13  789101  2018  208.000
```